# GET parameters not being correctly passed by RewriteRule

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wrote a simple regex for my application's API:

```
^api/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.([^$/?=&]+)(?:\?(.*))?$
```

this becomes

```
/app/api/$1.php?action=$2&format=$3&$4
```

In my testing, the regex works perfectly, constructing correct URLs, but the PHP script is not reporting any GET parameters apart from the `action` and `format` parameters. The .htaccess which is placed in / is

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
RewriteEngine on
#If the URL is just /api, give them the docs
RewriteRule ^api/?$ /app/api/apidoc.php [L]
#Example api/user/update.json?x=fff&y=gggg
#http://refiddle.com/2ss
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.([^$/?=&]+)(\?(.*))?$ /app/api/$1.php?action=$2&format=$3&$4 [L]
#Example api/user/update?x=000&y=ffe
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/([^/.&=]+)(\?((.*)*))?$ /app/api/$1.php?action=$2&$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to capture additional query string parameters. Instead, append them with the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag.

```
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.([^$/?=&]+) /app/api/$1.php?action=$2&format=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Adjust your `RewriteRule` accordingly.

Comment: Ah! I didn't notice that flag! I'll see if it works (though I don't doubt your answer one bit).

Comment: It probably worked, but the server is giving internal server errors now, strangely...
http://pastie.org/private/b0domlrskpr5hrfxx6a

Comment: For some reason, it didn't like the [L] flag, which I removed since it wasn't necessary for anything but very slight performance gains.