# Issue with URL slug.

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, slug

I can't seem to obtain the second part of the url slug. I currently have my .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?id=$1
```

And get this:

```
http://example.com/user/john
```

And now can't get this to work:

```
 http://example.com/user/john?o=last
```

How can I obtain `$_GET['o']`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11760282/1628832 ?

Comment: How can I get my url to work like that? http://example.com/user/john/last

Comment: What is the URL you want to redirect it to? is user/john real folder? What is the original URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need QSA (Query String Append) flag to preserve existing queries while redirecting.
2. You don't need 2 rules just for handling a trailing slash.

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```